# How do I make the Textbox component of a DatePicker read-only in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight

I am creating a simple application in Silverlight 5 to test another application's ability to pull data from it. The goal is to have as many input types as possible to test the other application's versatility. I am trying to add a DatePicker to a part of this form with the following code:

```
<sdk:DatePicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Height="25" Width="190" >
</sdk:DatePicker>
```

This works perfectly fine, but I want to make the TextBox component of the DatePicker read-only. The reason for this is that I want only valid dates to be entered into this text box, since I am then pulling the text from it and putting into a DataGrid. Any help would be appreciated! And if you need more information from me, just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own control that inherits from DatePicker:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

public class ReadonlyDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var textBox = this.GetTemplateChild("TextBox") as DatePickerTextBox;
        textBox.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Add the namespace to your project in your page:

```
xmlns:MyControls="clr-namespace:MyControlsNamespace"
```

Then reference your DatePicker using your namespace alias:

```
<MyControls:ReadonlyDatePicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Height="25" Width="190" >
</MyControls:ReadonlyDatePicker>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed, and in implementing it I learned how to implement user-created controls. This is my first time using Silverlight, so your help was very valuable to me.

Thank you for editing your answer to make it more understandable, too. I was able to find that out on my own, but hopefully if other people have the same problem they'll be able to learn from this, too.

Comment: I needed to add this line. `textBox.IsEnabled = false;`